# Are questions about asking what a song is okay?

Tags: discussion

Are questions about asking what a song is okay? For example, by giving a link to a brief recorded file that I hum? Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Covered by the FAQ, which summarizes stuff from here on Meta:

> Musical Practice and Performance - Stack Exchange is for musicians, students, and enthusiasts. Topics include practice & performance, composition, technique, theory, and history. "Listening recommendations", song identification, and shopping recommendations are off-topic.

Comment: I have tried midomi.com, but couldn't find the right song. Do you have some recommendations?

Comment: @Tim Not offhand. You could try posting in our chatroom, but it's very infrequently visited.

Comment: Perhaps the tips on [this page](http://www.labnol.org/internet/find-name-of-songs/12316/) might help.

Answer (score 0):

I do know that in this case, grooveshark is a great, but no perfect.  I have come across this particular problem and later was fixed on certain song.  Note that I do not know by what process it was fixed.  *I felt the question was off topic as I read it.*

I hope this helps.  However, as you can see that got me thinking...
Grooveshark does have a "This is not the right song" option, and that's as far as it goes, to my knowledge.